# Body Content Repetition in Modal Content

Tags: jquery, html, xml, twitter-bootstrap, xslt

there is a problem in my code cause repetition in body content of the model every time i click the button show Could any one help me ?

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename) {
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
}
else {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
try { xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document" } catch (err) { } // Helping IE11
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
};

function ShowForm() {

xml = loadXMLDoc("../XSLT/DecForm.xml");
xsl = loadXMLDoc("../XSLT/DeclarationForm.xslt");

if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
    xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
    resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
    document.getElementById("DeclarationDataDiv").appendChild(resultDocument);
}

$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-title').text("Declaration Form")

})
$('#myModal').modal('show');

return false
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function ShowForm(){
xml = loadXMLDoc("../XSLT/DecForm.xml");
xsl = loadXMLDoc("../XSLT/DeclarationForm.xslt");

if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
    xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
    resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
  $("#DeclarationDataDiv").html("").append(resultDocument);
}
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-title').text("Declaration Form")
})
$('#myModal').modal('show');
return false};
```